# Schedule an event - spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My application ( spring -  angularjs)  provides the ability to save a reunion type with a future date, and I want to send a notification (already implemented) to the specific user that the date of the reunion is close.

So what I need basically is to watch the database for any close date and act upon it. Now I've concluded some searches and I found `@scheduled` but it does not fulfill my needs and it's used for other things and there's `entity listeners` but it's not meant to be used as triggers.

Anyone got an idea how can I implement this with spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might go with scheduling a task which can check current date with the entered future reunion date. If this date is close as per your business logic, you can trigger mail notification. You can use task scheduler for this which comes with spring core. You can schedule a method like -

```
 <task:scheduled-tasks>
  <task:scheduled ref="myScheduler" method="scheduledMethod" fixed-delay="1000" />
 </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Then write a simple scheduled method with -

```
@Component
public class MyScheduler {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyScheduler.class);

public void scheduledMethod(){
logger.debug("running task again and again");
}
}
```